# Port 445 replacement in windows

Tags: windows, networking, smb

I need to replace my 445 port of my 2 NAS servers connected across 2 sites to any other port. My isp has blocked 445. I can't use VPN, port redirection or forwarding. I tried changing (TCP port for windows-ds service) services file in windows>systen32>drivers>etc but seems to have no effect. Is their anyway to replace the 445 port in windows registry or at any other place in windows?
Thanks

Comment: Are you honestly using SMB over the Public Internet? That's extremely unsafe. There's a good reason your ISP has blocked this port. [Here's one.](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2018/05/10/one-year-later-eternalblue-exploit-wannacryptor/)

Comment: I understand the risks.My isp is ok if i can use any other port for smb however is their any work around  the port replacement

Answer (score 2):

Port 445 is used by Windows for SMB Direct over TCP/IP. According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301240) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, the port can't be changed:

> This can't be done. Windows does not support TCP ports other than 445/139.

The answer cites [this source](http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php) as one reference for this.

As a workaround you could configure NAT on both ends of your connection to translate port 445 to another port for transport through your ISP's network.

SMB should **never** be used over an untrusted network connection. It was not designed to be used in this way and it is [completely insecure](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2018/05/10/one-year-later-eternalblue-exploit-wannacryptor/).

If you insist on using it on this way, at minimum ensure you [disable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and) SMB version 1.

Comment: I would change your minimum requirement to simply indicate the author should use SMBv3.  SMBv1 should never be used for obvious reasons, and while SMBv2 is slightly better, it's still not secure compared to SMBv3

Comment: @Ramhound unless there is newer guidance which conflicts Microsoft [discourages disabling SMB v2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and).

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the risks involved in running SMB over the Internet,
especially when using SMBv1 with older NAS machines, there might be
a simple solution. However, I hope you are in contact with
your ISP and have taken extreme precautions, including isolating
the vulnerable computers from the rest of the network.

Since Windows XP there is a built-in ability in Microsoft Windows to set up
network ports forwarding. With it, any incoming TCP connection (IPv4 or IPv6)
to local port can be redirected to another local port or even to port on a
remote computer, without the need for a service that listens on this port.

To set it up, use the
[netsh command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts).

The syntax is :

> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport

Where

- `listenaddress` – is a local IP address waiting for a connection.
- `listenport` – local listening TCP port (the connection is waited on it).
- `connectaddress` – is a local or remote IP address (or DNS name) to which the incoming connection will be redirected.
- `connectport` – is a TCP port to which the connection from listenport is forwarded to.

You may then forward any external-incoming port to port 445, where I hope
that it will be picked up by the SMB service.

For more information see :

- [Port Forwarding in Windows](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/)
- [Windows Netsh Interface Portproxy](https://parsiya.net/blog/2016-06-07-windows-netsh-interface-portproxy/)

Comment: FYI i am using dell Nx3230 windows 2016 storage server

Comment: Does that mean that this solution applies or not?

Comment: I was jst double checking as i reckon i saw xp os smewhere.will let u knw once i do the same and appreciate ur concern

Comment: Hi again, I tried to follow the above procedure using the command "interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=445 listenaddress=10.xx.10.xx connectport=27001 connectaddress=10.xx.10.xx" after checking the listen ports using this command "netstat -ano | findstr :27001" i am not able to find any listen ports. I have "ipv6" enabled as well as "iphelper" enabled. Any Insights